# To cover the page side to side with a div?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhGnx.png)

How do i fill those borders at the side of those div elements?
I want the background-color property of the div to cover the area it is on completely side to side

this is my css for both of those div:

```
.res {
    background-color: coral;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: fill;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

as you see, i've tried everything i found, but none of those worked

Comment: share html code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

to your CSS file. It should fix it.